# track a lot of batch jobs (start and end time)

Tags: grafana, jobs, influxdb, tracking

we have a lot of jobs (for example batch jobs), that are executed each day. Therefor we’d like to have an overview of all jobs.

→ track start time and end time (–> complete runtime).

All of these infos should be available in a visualisation.

Is InflixDB with Grafana a good solution for this or do you recommend another app?

Answer (score 1):

I think InfluxDB and Grafana are really a good starting point to collect data from your services.
You'll also need to integrate some type of metrics library and an exporter in your code.
On Java you could use Micrometer (https://micrometer.io/) and Prometheus.
Here you can find more information about them: https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus

After having integrated metrics in your code you simply need to configure Grafana to use data from InfluxDB and configure InfluxDB to scrape your metrics endpoint.

Comment: thanks for your answer. If i "only" want to track for examle BATCH-Jobs, is prometheus then also a good solution?